# Can't snap mesh correctly

Tags: snapping

I made a duplicate of a mesh I modelled and moved it along the Y-axis. Now I want the original mesh and the duplicate to line up but no matter what I try i can not get them to line up. It has been driving my crazy. I have tried every single snap mode there is but none of them work. It keeps overshooting so the meshes overlap each other instead. Surely there must be an easy way to do this? I am boggled by the fact that this has prevented me from continuing my work for the past two hours.

The first image shows the vertices selected that I want to move. I press G and then Y to restrict the move to the Y axis. But even if I place my cursor at the bottom vertex before I start moving it doesn't snap correctly. The snap is all over the place.

The second image shows the closest I can get, which is not what I am trying to achive

Thank you in advance for any help!

BLENDER FILE: https://we.tl/t-ul78z0mBVh

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have the vertices right through the mesh selected before snapping? - The image shows you're not in wireframe or x-ray mode (SHFT-Z or ALT-X) which you'd need to be to select all the vertices. If that isn't it, try disabling snapping on the toolbar, then hover the mouse over the target vertex and G >Y > CTRL > Click.

Comment: please share your object: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Yes X-ray is on. I just quickly took these screenshots afterwards to show the problem. G>Y>CTRL>Click yeilds the same result as in my screenshoot.

Comment: As @moonboots comments we'll need to see your Blend file in that case because there's something we aren't understanding in your mesh layout.

Comment: What are your snap settings?

Comment: @JohnEason here is the file: https://we.tl/t-ul78z0mBVh

Comment: Try setting vertex snapping to Closest in the dropdown.

Comment: I have it on closest. It still snaps wrong. I have also tried all the other modes. Nothing works. Did you check the file and try it yourself? Can you get it to snap correctly?

Comment: Yes I have now tried it and I guess that snapping isn't going to work here because of the geometry of the selected part that you want to move. You'll also find that you have 336 duplicate vertices on that mesh although merging them by distance doesn't affect the snapping. Not sure what the answer is to be honest.

Comment: @JohnEason thank you for taking a look. I have only been using blender for about a week so I feel a bit lost at times. I will have to find another method of modeling this thing, starting with cleaning up some duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple. You don't even need to duplicate your mesh.

First, to get your origin in line for the mesh, go here and enable *Transform Origins Only*:

[image]

Then move the origin outside the range of the mesh on the Y-Axis. Then, enable snapping and move the origin on the y-ais to your corner vertex. (your snapping wasn't working since it snaps to the closest vertex) Then add a mirror modifier and set the Axis to `Y`.

Problem solved!

Edit:

To not do this manually and all, keep one mesh and add an array modifier on it and enable the merge option. You can also enable the merge option on the mirror, and you can also enable clipping, so when you join it, you can move it out again and your problem will be solved.

Edit 2:

The solution to your snapping problem: Move the object outside the range of the mesh on the Y-Axis. Then, enable snapping and move the mesh on the y-ais to your corner vertex. (your snapping wasn't working since it snaps to the closest vertex).

Also, you can always apply the array modifier by using the dropdown menu on the modifier, and then you can easily edit the rest of them and they won't be uniform.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this is not what I am looking for. The "mirror" in this case is longer so it needs to be merged with another set on the opposite side. This solution fixes the problem on one side but then I have the same problem on the other side, i.e, I cannot get it to join on the other side.

Comment: @Anotherfeffe I take it that your mesh is duplicated many times along the Y-Axis? Well, then, just use an array!

Comment: @Anotherfeffe Check my edits.

Comment: Array doesn't work. It doesn't let you edit the mesh of the arrayed mesh. An array is basically a constant mirror of the original, They are not going to be unique. They just share the basic elements. I thought I would save myself some time by modelling one and then duplicating it. Turns out this was a waste of time lol. I should just do each one individually.

Comment: @Anotherfeffe No, just add the array modifier, and apply the modifier using the dropdown on the modifier. Then you can easily edit the rest and make them unique and won't have to duplicate them.

Comment: @Anotherfeffe Check edit 2

Comment: I understand what you mean but the array will not work with my continued workflow. I need to match it up on the other end as well so the problem remains. It’s difficult to explain. I tried your other suggestion and I’m starting to feel stupid now because I’m not able to do it no matter what. I posted the blender file if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

depending on what result you expect, I believe there are multiple ways to *"Line-up"*:

Anyway if you are using **Auto-merge option** *(Edit Mode)* in **Tools > Auto-merge**, make sure the threshold is not too big for the scale of the model not to merge multiple points into one.

1. *(MERGE / NON-MERGE Option)* Add mirror modifier with some Empty axis as a mirroring object, and enable "Clipping"
2. *(NON-MERGE Option)* Take the desired points and scale towards a 3D Cursor / Active Element - S, Y, 0 + Enter and replicate for the other side
3. *(MERGE OPTION)* Delete the Middle faces, select the outer edges and **Ctrl + E > Bridge Edge Loops**

But in general, scaling towards desired points in Y-axis should do.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but these are not an option. Option 1 fixes the problem but only on one side. You see this duplicate is longer than the original and it means I also have to line it up on the other side. Option 2 ruins the mesh. It looses its original form in the Y-axis. 3. Might work. I will give it a go. 

I honestly can't believe that such a simple operation is so involved and complicated. It should be as easy as clicking two vertices and getting them to snap. Or dragging the vertices you want to snap to the point you want to snap it. How is this such a big deal?

Comment: "It should be as easy as clicking two vertices and getting them to snap. Or dragging the vertices you want to snap to the point you want to snap it. How is this such a big deal?" - Snapping the two point together is simple operation, try enabling Auto-Merge (N > Tool > Options > Auto Merge checkbox) and enable Snap (Magnet Icon, Vertex selection). Let me know if this helps... ;)